# Move all pins to another board OR make a public board a private (secret board)

Tags: pinterest

I made a Pinterest board public by accident. I spent several hours on it and have about 300 pins. I want to make the board a private board but after digging around all I could find was information saying that isn't possible. Is this really so?

If not possible to change it from public to private, is there a way to bulk move or copy pins to a private (secret) board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Move/Copy Bulk Pins

After Searching over Internet, I found this tool [Pin4Ever!](https://www.pin4ever.com). May be it will help you.

#### Pin Better With Pin4Ever!

Pin4Ever is a set of power tools for Pinterest that help you quickly protect, organize, create, and upload your pins.

#### Pin4Ever Features

- ***Bulk Image Uploading***

Pin multiple images from your local drive or images from the web, including   Facebook,   Instagram,   Pinterest, and other sites, with an optional time delay between pins.

- **Bulk Pin Editing - Move, Copy, Delete, Rearrange**

Move, Copy, Delete, and Rearrange pins from your boards or any pin you see. (You must own the pin in order to Move, Delete, or Rearrange it.)

Answer (score 3):

## Moving Pins to another Board

After searching around, I have [found](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/105060603777319720/) a lot of [things](https://www.facebook.com/pinterest/posts/473689672671096) pointing out that you currently can [only move one pin](http://timewiththea.com/2013/03/18/how-to-move-your-pins-on-pinterest/) at a time.

To do this, hover over the pin, click on the Pencil icon, and then change the board. See [this image](http://i2.wp.com/timewiththea.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/move-pins-3-timewiththea.jpg).

It is evident that a lot of people are asking for the ability to move multiple pins at once as a feature, and I am sure that it would be available in the near future, but until then, one by one.

*Note: This is without external tools.

### External tools

[pin4ever](https://www.pin4ever.com/) (as pointed out by [Gurpreet Singh](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/75278/gurpreet-singh)) can do bulk pin moving, which will help in your scenario.

---

## Making a public board Secret

Sadly, you cannot make a public board private/secret. You can only make a secret board public, not the other way around.

I found [this](http://help.pinterest.com/en/articles/secret-boards#Web):

> You can't edit a public board to make it secret. You can only create new secret boards.
>
> Similarly, you can't edit an existing Pin to move it to a secret board—since public boards or Pins may already have Pins or likes, you can't make them secret.
>
> You can Pin from a public board to a secret one. This is like creating a secret copy instead of moving the original Pin.

*Note: This is without external tools.

---

## Conclusion:

So **you cannot make that Public board Secret**, **nor can you move all the pins at once without external tools**. Given the functionality as it **currently** stands, you will have to **create a new Secret board**, and then **move the pins over**.

If 'pin4ever' works for bulk pin moving (I have not personally tried this), this will be your best bet.

Otherwise, if the board is embarrassing or something, **you can delete it, but you will have to find all the pins from scratch again**, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, yes, you can.

I created a secret board. Then opened the board I wanted to change and **copied** all the pins to the secret board. As of 5 minutes ago when I did it, I was able to move 50 pins at a time (but they all had to be clicked individually). After **copying** (not moving) all my pins, I double checked the secret board to ensure everything I wanted was there, and then deleted the public board.

So far all is well!